# Maximal accuracy of logistic regression on the n-parity problem

Tags: parity, logistic-regression, bit-strings

Consider the standard logistic regression ('LR') function, $ y = \sigma(w^T \cdot x + b) $, where $\sigma$ is the logistic function ('sigmoid'). When checking the accuracy, we will consider the argmax of this classifier as it's output (binary output and not probabilistic output).

Consider the $n$-dimensional parity binary classification problem, given a binary string $x$, the ground truth $y=parity(x)$ is the parity of the number of $1$ bits in $x$, meaning $0$ if there are an even number of $1$-bits, and $1$ otherwise.

For example, in $2$ dimensions, we have $parity(00)=0$, $parity(01)=1$, $parity(10)=1$, and $parity(11)=0$ which is exactly the XOR problem, for which the maximal accuracy of the LR is $0.75$ (that is, just implementing an AND).

In the $3$ dimensional case, using some geometrical intuition, I managed to build a solution for LR with $0.75$ accuracy as well.

I'm wondering what is the formula for the general case, i.e.,

What is the maximal accuracy of LR for the $n$-dimensional parity problem?

Comment: You might want to describe the classifier output; does it pick 0 or 1, or can it output a probability?

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I've clarified that part in the question.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems like for $n\in\{2k, 2k+1\}$, the answer should be $2^{-2k} \sum_{i=0}^{k} \pmatrix{2k \\ i} \to \frac12$ as $k \to \infty$. Trickier to prove it, though.

Comment: That's seems almost right @Adam, take a look at my question in MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439652/perceptron-logistic-regression-accuracy-on-the-n-bit-parity-problem